# Need clarification on how the Google Sheets API limits are applied

Tags: google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

From [Usage Limits help page](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/limits):

> This version of the Google Sheets API has a limit of 500 requests per 100 seconds per project, and 100 requests per 100 seconds per user.

Let’s take it apart:

1. `500 requests per 100 seconds per project` - This is applied to my project. I use my project credentials to make each request.
2. `100 requests per 100 seconds per user` -  When I make a request, I also include the OAuth token of a user that permitted me to update their workbook.

Question about the **per-user** part:

- Is there anything the user can do themselves (like reach out to Google) to increase the quota just for them? Or is it me who needs to talk to Google to increase the quota for all users of my project simultaneously?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `500 requests per 100 seconds per project` - This is applied to my project. I use my project credentials to make each request.
2. `100 requests per 100 seconds per user` -  When I make a request, I also include the OAuth token of a user that permitted me to update their workbook.

As you can see there are two types of quotas project based quotas these are the quotas that are applied to your project as a whole.  Then there are user based quotes these quotas a are applied to the users of your project / application.

Project based quotas can be extended you can apply for an extension and google may grant you that extension which will increase the number of requests your project as a whole can make.

User based quotas are more like flood protection they ensure that a single user of your application can not make to many requests at once flooding the server.  User based quotas can not be extended.

> Is there anything the user can do themselves (like reach out to Google) to increase the quota just for them? Or is it me who needs to talk to Google to increase the quota for all users of my project simultaneously?

To answer your question there is nothing the user can do to increase the quota this is your project and only you have access to increase the project based quota.

There is nothing you can do to increase he user based quotas.